# Unamed Array - protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-go

I want to receive a list (array) of message using protobuf. The idea would be to receive something like:

```json
[
  {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2"
  },
  {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2"
  }
]
```

However, when defining protobuf messages I can get ride of the top name in this array. For example:

```
message MyFields {
  string field1 = 1;
  string field2 = 2;
}

message MyMessage {
  repeated MyFields some_identifier = 1;
}
```

Which would create something like:

```json
{
  "some_identifier":
 [
   {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2"
   },
   {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2"
   }
 ]
}
```

Not even sure if this is possible with protobuf.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

Protobuf requires that messages comprise fields and fields have a name, a type (and a field number).

See [Definining a Message Type](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#simple)

In your example, the repeated message field would have no name and this isn't permitted.

Answer (score 0):

did you try with a `repeated` [Map](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps)? Like:

```
message MyFields {
  map<string, string> MyMap = 1;
}

message MyMessage {
  repeated MyFields some_identifier = 1;
}
```